# Что делает эта функция ? И зачем её используют?

Tags: python, случайные-числа

```
random.seed(datetime.datetime.now())
```

Comment: Генераторы псевдослучайных чисел работают, выполняя некоторую операцию над значением. Обычно это значение является предыдущим числом, генерируемым генератором. Однако при первом использовании генератора прежнего значения нет.

Посещение генератора псевдослучайных чисел дает ему его первое "предыдущее" значение. Каждое начальное значение будет соответствовать последовательности генерируемых значений для данного генератора случайных чисел. То есть, если вы даете одно и то же семя дважды, вы получаете одну и ту же последовательность чисел дважды

Comment: единственное, что я могу себе представить где имело бы смысл использовать `datetime.datetime.now()` в качестве аргумента для `random.seed()` - это функция вызывающаяся параллельно (например на разных узлах кластера), которая должна использовать __одинаковые__ псевдослучайные значения в том случае если вызов происходит в тот же момент времени. Но гораздо проще было бы использовать константу в данном случае. Если нужно сгенерировать случайное число и нет необходимости вопроизведения того же генерируемого числа то лучше вызывать `random.seed()` без параметра или вообще не вызывать его

Comment: Дело в том, что по умолчанию в Python в качестве ядра для генератора случайных чисел как раз и используется системное время.  Поэтому, если нужны разные последовательности, то seed можно и не задавать. Поэтому данная функция, на сколько я понимаю, призвана вам объяснить, как работает seed "по умолчанию". Возможно, это сделано с дидактической целью, продемонстрировать отличия от других языков. Например, в С++ (в противоположность Python), все как раз наоборот: явное задание системного времени в качестве параметра seed является обязательным условием получение разных последовательностей.